# Is possible organize Google Photos by folder in upload?

Tags: google-photos

I love Google Photos, but the big problem I have with it is that the folders it syncs get mixed up instead of being separated by Albums.

Is there a way to solve this?

Thank you!

Comment: @jhamon please avoid answering in the comments, even if it's an ultrashort answer. Perhaps you can post an answer with screenshots?

Answer (score 4):

I have faced the same issue and after only finding a single paid app that can do it, I have given up and written my own - http://jiotty-photos-uploader.yudichev.net/. It's free and open source.

> Jiotty Photos Uploader is a simple desktop application for Windows, macOS and Linux that scans a folder, including all subfolders, for photos and videos, and uploads them to your Google Photos gallery arranging into albums according to the directory structure.

Comment: Very good, but I need a solution to mobile.

Answer (score -1):

I assume you have already uploaded the photos right? Please see steps below (I'm using Android phone). Also, I have screenshots, but I can't upload pictures here - can someone please teach me how?

1. Open Google Photos. Pictures are arranged with the latest modified picture at the top.
2. Long press on any one picture, and a small circle appears at the left side of each picture. Click on the circles of pictures that you want to group in one album.
3. In the upper right part of the screen are four icons - Share icon, Add icon, Delete icon and three dots. Select the "Add" icon. A "Create" list will appear, then select the first item,  "Album"
4. You will be asked to type in the Album Name. After, just click the check mark in the upper left of the screen. And you're done!
5. You can check your newly created Album in the "Home" page of Google Photos app (the page that appears when you open the app). In the lowest part of the screen there are "Photos", "Albums", "For you" and "Sharing". Click on "Albums". You will see in the "Album" section your newly created album.

Comment: Yes, on Google Photos I know it's possible.
What I can't do is make the photos on my phone, when uploaded to Google Photos, group by albums. Is it clear now?